# Performance issue with UIGraphics ImageContext

Tags: ipad, ios7, sprite-kit, uigraphicscontext

I have written a simple 2D animation application on the iPad using Sprite Kit.  The only difficult part of this application is to clip an image (.png) with a calculated polygon (a shadow).  Upon investigation, it appeared to me that the only way to accomplish this was to use UIImage and a UIBezier path (Note: my path does not require the full capabilities of a Bezier path, a simple CGPath will work in my case.).  I wrote the following method to accomplish this clipping:

```
- (UIImage *) maskImage: (UIImage *)originalImage toPath: (UIBezierPath *)path
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions (originalImage.size, NO, 0.0f);
    [path addClip];
    [originalImage drawAtPoint: CGPointZero];
    UIImage *maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext ();
    return maskedImage;
}
```

The results of this operation are eventually passed to:

```
SKSpriteNode *node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture: [SKTexture textureWithImage: [self buildShadowMask]]];
```

When this code is executed using the iOS simulator, it runs extremely quickly, in fact, in real time.  However, when I run this on an actual iPad (iPad Air or iPad 4G), it runs extremely slowly.  So, my questions are: Why is this method of clipping an image so slow on the actual iPad device?  Is there anyway to clip an image (with a simple path) that would be faster?  Is this an issue with UIGraphicsContext or Sprite or both?  I would greatly appreciate any advice or guidance that anyone can give me.  Thanks very much!

Comment: it's faster in the Simulator because your Mac's CPU is several magnitudes faster than the iPad CPU. You may want to look into SKCropNode to do the cropping (not sure if it's cropping you want).

Comment: I first tried using SKCropNode and SKShapeNode (for the path) as the mask node, but never could get that to work.  Maybe, I should revisit that approach and post that code and see if I can get help on getting it to work. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: You can add a layer mask to the `UIImageView` and use a `CAShapeLayer` as the mask and just update the `CAShapeLayer`'s `path` with the `bezierPath.CGPath`

Comment: @Paul.s I like your suggestion, but I cannot seem to get it to work.  This is my code fragment: inline `UIImageView *iv =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: originalImage];
    CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    mask.path  = path.CGPath;
    mask.frame = iv.frame;
    iv.layer.mask = mask;
    iv.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    return iv.image;`  Any suggestions?